# Is Flask loaded just once on the server or every time someone visits site?

Tags: python, flask

I am just about ready to deploy my Flask based website but before I do, I would like to know if the Flask framework is loaded for each session or if it is loaded just once on the server.  The reason I ask is because I have a lot of python libraries to load and I want to know if I should load them all at once (if Flask is only loaded once) or load them on a page by page basis (if Flask is loaded for each session).  It is really a question about getting the best performance for the end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask and all of your dependencies are loaded once when you start your web server, so no need to worry about startup time.

Comment: If this is true, that raises another question. What in the server implementation needs to be considered for it to only load once?